# Quantum many-body gapless systems which are off-critical

Tags: quantum-spin, phase-transition, many-body, correlation-functions, critical-phenomena

As we know that quantum many-body systems can be roughly classified into two classes --- gapped phases and gapless phases --- depending on whether there is a nonzero energy gap above the ground state(s) in the thermodynamic limit.

Within the gapless phase, there are a subclass of systems called critical phase, which are characterized by a infinite-large correlation length in the thermodynamic limit.

My question: are there some simple gapless quantum many-body systems that are not critical? Or equivalently speaking, I am looking for a system with ground-state sector in the continuum spectrum and a finite correlation length.

Comment: Could you clarify the question: you are looking for a system without a gap and with finite correlations? Like a normal metal?

Comment: Yeah, more strictly speaking, a system with a zero many-body gap, which is defined as the gap above the ground state(s) in the large system-size limit, but having a finite correlation length.

Comment: I am not sure why normal metal is not a sufficient example: what is *many-body gap*? The gap due to the interactions as opposed to the gap due to an underlying lattice (as in semiconductors)?

Comment: @Vadim Could give a detailed Hamiltonian for the normal metal you mentioned because I don’t know some metal with a finite correlation length. By many-body gap, I simply mean the gap in the thermodynamic limit in contrast to a gap due to a finite system size.

Comment: Are you saying that Fermi liquid has infinite correlations? I think there is some terminology misunderstanding here.

Comment: Are you familiar with Goldstone's theorem and the idea of spontaneously broken continuous symmetries? These are the most obvious systems which are always gapless but they have an innate energy scale (the "spin stiffness"), so they are not critical. I can try to write a fuller answer on this depending on your background with the above concepts. A much more exotic example is the deconfined phase of a compact gauge theory with a continuous gauge group.

Comment: @Vadim By "infinite correlations" I believe the poster means that the system is critical. One can actually think of metals/Fermi liquids as critical states. If one perturbs a free fermion system by interactions, one finds that nearly all interactions are marginal and the system explores a family of (metallic) critical points parametrized by the Landau parameters. The only relevant interaction is due to forward scattering, which leads to the BCS instability and the development of a mass gap.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt My supervisor told me an example: Example 2 in Section 7 of
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104276093
It seems that the excitation dispersion is like spin-wave in ferromagnetism.